# getting numbers from edittext from last number to first number one by one

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to read numbers from `Edit Text` one by one in such way that whenever I Click the button, I will get one number and next number on the next click.

```
public class addition extends AppCompatActivity {



  EditText editText1,editText2;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.additionop);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstnum);
        editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondnum);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int num1=  Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
                int num2=Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
```

Comment: What format is the EditText's string in? CSV / separated by spaces?

Comment: number edit text field @DiscoS2

Comment: why is android-studio tagged though?

Comment: You want to read the numbers from 1 editText box? so let's say u have 12345, u want to read: `onClick()` - **1** , `onClick()` - **2** , `onClick()` - **3** .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want number from the last one to the first one,do it like this:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int index1=-1,index2=-1;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(index1<0)index1=editText1.getText().length()-1;
            if(index2<0)index2=editText2.getText().length()-1;
            if(index1>=0){
                int num1=  Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString().charAt(index1));
                index1--;
            }
            if(index2>=0){
                int num2=Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString().charAt(index2));
                index2--;
            }
        }
    };
```

It is similar to get number from the first one to the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Add these variable at class level

```
public int index = 0;
EditText[] editTexts = new EditText[2]; // as per your size
```

After initialization do this in `onCreate`

```
editTexts[0] = editText1;
editTexts[1] = editText2;
```

In `onClick` do this

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(editTexts[index++].getText().toString());
```

**Note:** This way you can have as many `EditText` as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out something like this

```
public class addition extends AppCompatActivity { 

    EditText editText1,editText2;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    boolean EditText1, EditText2;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.additionop); 

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate); 
        editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstnum); 
        editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondnum); 
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 

                if(!EditText1){
                     int num1= Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString()); 
                EditText1 = true;
                }
                else if(!EditText2){
                int num2=Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
                EditText2 = true;               
                }
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean shouldShowNum1 = true;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int number;
            if ( shouldShowNum1 ) {
                shouldShowNum1 = false;
                number = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
            } else {
                shouldShowNum1 = false;
                number = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
            }
            // do whatever you want with number
        }
}
```

Comment: can i get number from edit text one by one by this?? @Disco

Comment: Well if you only have 2 yes. If you have more then you're better off using @Rohit5k2's solution

Answer (score 0):

If u want to read numbers one by one from 1 editTextbox use:

```
int buttonClicked = 0;
int pos = 0;
int[] num = new int[];

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        String text = editText1.getText().toString(); //Get text from editText box      

        //Check if editText contains any text
        if(!text.equals("") 
        {   
            int length = editText.getText().toString().length(); //Get the lenght of the entered string  

            //Check if end of string has been reached
            if(buttonClicked <= length-1){          
                int number = Character.getNumericValue(text.charAt(buttonClicked)); //Get the next character

                //Check if character is a number, if not keep looking until the end of the string   
                while(number == -1 && buttonClicked <= length-1){  
                    number = Character.getNumericValue(text.charAt(buttonClicked)); //Get the next character
                    buttonClicked++; //Increment buttonClicked  
                }

                //Check if (last) character is a number
                if(number != -1){  
                    num[pos] =  number; //Save the number in the array  
                    pos++; //Increment the array position         
                    buttonClicked++ //Increment buttonClicked   
                }
            }
            //End of string has been reached
            else{
                //Maybe reset everything
                pos = 0;
                buttonClicked = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now: if u enter **178abc896** in your `editText` box.
Than the output will be as following:

> **1st** click - **num[0]** contains: **1**
>   **2nd** click - **num[1]** contains: **7**
>   **3rd** click - **num[2]** contains: **8**
>   **4th** click - **num[3]** contains: **8**
>   **5th** click - **num[4]** contains: **9**
>   **6th** click - **num[5]** contains: **6**